# Not getting response body when using ContentCachingResponseWrapper

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-async, spring-filter

I have a Spring Boot API in Scala with multiple endpoints. All endpoints are *async* and return `DeferredResult`. I want to use filters to log response body in some cases. I have created a filter with order 1 to cache requests and response as below:

```
@Component
@Order(1)
class ContentCachingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
  override def doFilterInternal(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, filterChain: FilterChain): Unit = {
    val requestToCache  = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request)
    val responseToCache = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response)
    filterChain.doFilter(requestToCache, responseToCache)
    responseToCache.copyBodyToResponse()
  }
}
```

My logging filter is similar to below (removed domain specific logic):

```
@Component
@Order(2)
class RequestResponseLoggingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  override def doFilterInternal(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, filterChain: FilterChain): Unit = {

    logger.info(
      s"Request -> URL : ${request.getMethod} ${request.getRequestURI} ${request.getParameterMap.asScala.stringRepresentation()}")
    logger.debug(
      s"Request Headers -> Content-type : ${request.getContentType} \\n Headers : ${new ServletServerHttpRequest(request).getHeaders}")

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response)

    logger.info(s"Response -> Status : ${response.getStatus}")

  }
}
```

I have to use `ContentCachingResponseWrapper` because I want to log the response body. However, even without trying to log the response body and just by introducing `ContentCachingResponseWrapper`, I don't get any response for calls to any endpoint. A local running instance returns an output like this on curl:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 197
.
.
.
<
* transfer closed with 197 bytes remaining to read
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (18) transfer closed with 197 bytes remaining to read
```

If I remove the `ContentCachingFilter`, the logging filter above works fine but if I try to log response body, the response stream is consumed and the response is no longer generated. Hence I need to use `ContentCachingFilter`.

I did find out that all this works if the endpoints are *synchronous*.
Could someone help me find out what is the problem and how to make this work with *asynchronous* endpoint?

Answer (score 11):

```
responseToCache.copyBodyToResponse()
```

change to :

```
if (requestToCache.isAsyncStarted()) {
  requestToCache.getAsyncContext().addListener(new AsyncListener() {
      public void onComplete(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException {
          responseToCache.copyBodyToResponse()
      }

      public void onTimeout(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException {
      }

      public void onError(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException {
      }

      public void onStartAsync(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException {
      }
  })
} else {
  responseToCache.copyBodyToResponse()
}
```

Comment: This worked in my case.

Comment: Spent all day looking for this answer. Kept seeing a 200 status code in the wrapped response in code, yet a 500 in the actual HTTP response. This async check was the key and now I can log all status codes. Thank you!

Comment: You saved my day, thank you!    (  In my case, the execution order: sync-filterChain(in)->Controller of DeferredResult<VO> method -> sync-filterChain(out) ->  async-filterChain(in) ->async-filterChain(out). It seems that the response returns to  the front-end just after sync-filterChain(out), not after async-filterChain(out), so of cause the sync-response-body is empty! )

Answer (score 0):

```
val requestToCache = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
val responseToCache = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
```

This two line  change to:

```
  if(!(request instanceof ContentCachingRequestWrapper)) {
     requestToCache = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
  }
  if(!(request instanceof ContentCachingResponseWrapper)){
     responseToCache = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(request);
  }
```

Comment: sorry I didn't see your reply. could you please tell me why I need to do that? Also, what will be the else part of above if statements?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, no http response after adding the ContentCachingResponseWrapper.  It was an order issue, once I changed the order of the calls, everything work as expected.  The next block is the wrong way, causing the symptoms

```
ContentCachingResponseWrapper wrappedResponse = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
wrappedResponse.copyBodyToResponse();
filterChain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, wrappedResponse);
```

This is the order that resolved my issue.

```
ContentCachingResponseWrapper wrappedResponse = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
filterChain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, wrappedResponse);
wrappedResponse.copyBodyToResponse();
```